# Java/Servlet: get current sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, datetime, locale

What I need to do is:

1) Get user's locale from request.

2) Create new sql.Date object with current date and time, based on user's locale

3) Write it in MySQL db, column type: TIMESTAMP

What I got is:

```
java.util.Locale locale = request.getLocale();

java.text.DateFormat dateFormat =
java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                        java.text.DateFormat.LONG, java.text.DateFormat.LONG, locale );

java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date( date.getTime() );
```

Date is OK, but have a problem with time - always 12:00:00 AM.

Any suggestions? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 17):

Even a more compact solution ;)

```
java.sql.Date timeNow = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 9):

There is one more simple solution for it.
use this code to get current date using java.util.Date

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date utilDate = cal.getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: A more compact solution is: 
`java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();`
`java.sql.Date timeNow = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());`

Answer (score 4):

If you want the time, you need a java.sql.Timestamp not a java.sql.Date, and a timestamp column in the database.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that [request.getLocale](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale()) uses the value of Accept-Language heading and may not always give you the correct locale.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the **time zone based on the locale may not be their actual time zone** .

An example: Here in Australia, the locale is 'en-AU', but we have a few time zones with up to 3 hours difference.

I'd guess in the US they have this problem too.

A possible solution is to **store  UTC time** instead. If the user then adjusts his timezone in, say, his prefrences, or you use some other method of passing the time zone (client/browser info say via AJAX) then you can adjust the UTC time based on that using a `java.util.Calendar` instance.

Comment: Thank you for that important note. Can you suggest an example of elegant solution?